# Why isn't it a common practice for languages to have method arguments passed inside method names?

Tags: programming-languages, language-design

Why is not it a common practice for languages to have method arguments passed *inside* method names?

For instance, wouldn't something like: `shop.Sell(15)Notebooks` (although looking pretty unusual) be more readable than `shop.SellNotebooks(15)`?

Also, this could simplify fluent APIs: instead of implementing additional interfaces for things like `money.Add(20).Dollars()` we could simply use methods: `money.Add(20)Dollars` and so on.

Comment: Languages that let you define mixfix operators/functions probably can do this.

Comment: To be honest, when reading a lot of code searching for something specific, searching for argument inside function name would slow me down quite a bit.

Comment: Related, but not duplicates (of this question): [Is there a language out there in which parameters are placed inside method name?](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/102906/121035) and [Is there a language that allows this syntax: add(elements)at(index);](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/120541/121035)

Comment: @Walfrat, I suppose syntax highlighting could solve these issues

Comment: Your examples could be rewritten as `shop.Sell(15_Notebooks)` or `money.Add(20_Dollars)`, with physical units integrated in the values. See [Are units of measurement unique to F#?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/107243/45249) for some examples of languages with this feature.

Comment: `money.Add(20).Dollars()` is an abomination

Comment: @CodesInChaos why so? Adding a fluent interface would likely make it more readable than something like `money.Add(MoneyFactory.GetDollars(20))`

Comment: @mouviciel probably, although these extend to more than simply units integration. Consider something like `driver.Take(person)To(airport)` etc. And although all of the examples could be implemented via fluent interfaces, methods would just eliminate additional complexity as I assumed below.

Comment: This is a pass-by-name call, like Objective-C: `[driver take:person to:airport]

Comment: @mouviciel except for pass-by-name thing does not allow to add post-arguments text (like in units examples) if I am not mistaken.

Comment: @bashis: See the update in my answer below.

Comment: You're correct in that, @bashis: [Why must the last part of an ObjC method name take an argument?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4479967) (answered by the language's creator)

Answer (score 6):

> For instance, wouldn't something like: shop.Sell(15)Notebooks (although looking pretty unusual) be more readable than shop.SellNotebooks(15)?

No, it wouldn't.

Programmers don't read code as English; *they read it as code.*  This:

```
shop.SellNotebooks(15);
```

is very straightforward; it means "Call the `SellNotebooks` method on the `shop` object, passing it 15 as a parameter."  This:

```
shop.Sell(15)Notebooks
```

means... Well, what does it mean, exactly?  It appears to call the `Sell` method on the `shop` object, but what's going on after that?

---

#### [Execution in the Kingdom of Nouns](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html)

In most single-dispatch object-oriented languages in common use today (such as Java and C++), the usual notation is **noun-verb.**  That is, you take an object (a noun), and you apply a verb to it (a method).  Doing things this way provides a consistent, easily understandable notation.

There have been a number of attempts to make such constructs more English-like, the most notable of which is the *fluent interface.*  When it works well, it is a joy:

```
var query = translations
    .Where   (t => t.Key.Contains("a"))
    .OrderBy (t => t.Value.Length)
    .Select  (t => t.Value.ToUpper());
```

or

```
var sizer = Sizer.FromImage(inputImage)
     .ToLocation(outputImage)
     .ReduceByPercent(50)
     .OutputImageFormat(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

When it doesn't, well, not so much:

```
money.Add(20).Dollars().And().TransferTo().MyCheckingAccount().In(3).Days();
```

How does this work under the hood, exactly?  Fluent interfaces are just like many other great ideas in computing; you can have too much of a good thing.

However, everyone understands this:

```
object.Verb(data);
```

And you don't have to squint that hard to figure out what it does.

Comment: Constructing fluent interface could occasionaly increase the complexity of the supporting code. For instance, if I would like to have something like `Sizer.FromImage(...).ToLocation(...)` the `FromImage` method would have to return an additional interface which would then have an extension method added over it (in case of C#). And while this is still worth the effort, wouldn't in-method arguments eliminate these steps at all, still providing almost-identical API?

Comment: @bashis: Of course.  Well, not in-method arguments.  The language construct you propose would be quite difficult for a language compiler to parse.  My point is that `object.Verb()` notation is easy to parse, both for the programmer and the compiler.

Comment: @RobertHarvey could you please elaborate on the presumed difficulty for the compiler? It is not quite clear to me how `Foo(bar)foo` is more difficult than `Foofoo(bar)`. In the end these could be precompiled as "native" functions and this "mixfix" syntax could just stay as a sugar.

Comment: Yes, but to what end?  Which is easier to figure out what is going on under the hood, `Foo(bar)foo` or `Foofoo(bar)`?

Comment: @RobertHarvey i think this is more of a habit. Provided both are single method calls I don't see quite a difference in getting the inner implementation idea.

Comment: Yes, and it's a very good habit to have.  Consistency is the key here.  Why have two ways to write something, when one way perfectly suffices?

Comment: @RobertHarvey well, we already have plenty of examples where there are several ways to achieve the same thing. One could be extension methods in C#: instead of writing `StaticClass.DoSomethingStatic(arg)` we can write `arg.DoSomethingStatic()` which is really convenient and increases readability a lot.

Comment: @bashis:  What increases readability is *consistency, not variety.*  The more different ways you make to represent something, the more time it takes to mentally figure out which way is in play.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't think variety is evil on its own. It is more about using the right tool to get the job done. Also, consistency doesn't always increase readability: otherwise things like fluent interfaces would've never appeared, would they?

Comment: But fluent interfaces *preserve the noun-verb notation.*  Can you see that?

Comment: @RobertHarvey how do mixfixes change that? All these sentences are actually actions (verbs), there are no fundumental differences between them and native methods. All I am trying to say is that as long as fluent things are really commonly used, _maybe_ it could be reasonable to provide language features that would simplify things a bit? This has already happened for the enumerator pattern in C# (which combined with extension methods led to amazing things like LINQ).

Comment: Linq is a fluent interface.  Did you hear what I said in the last comment?  *Noun-verb notation is preserved in fluent interfaces.* Enumerators and `foreach` are not the same thing as what you are describing in your question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey again, how exactly does mixfix break the _noun-verb notation_?

Comment: You mean other than the fact that it's not `noun.verb()` notation anymore?

Comment: @RobertHarvey isn't it? I thought more of `job.AddWorkers(10)` vs `job.Add(10)Workers` thing like stated in the question. To me `AddWorkers_` is not much more of a verb than `Add_Workers`. Probably you are arguing to the arugment placement and if so, that is what the topic is all about: do we really need arguments placed _after_ methods except for conservative reasons? To me it really seams that, discaring established habits, this could increase readability at some point.

Comment: "Because object-oriented notation is noun-verb" -- except that the term "object oriented" was originally coined to describe Smalltalk, which has almost exactly the kind of argument-within-method-name notation described in the question, so this clearly isn't a valid argument.

Comment: @PeriataBreatta: Then use Smalltalk.  Is that language even on the [Tiobe index](http://www.tiobe.com/tiobe-index/)?  The OP did use the phrase "common practice" in his question; I wasn't expecting to address languages not in common use.

Comment: Reducing OOP to a noun-verb relationship is silly. I dislike seeing this linguistic approach being pulled out of thin air, since it has no basis in either OOP or programming language ergonomics. There is no standard OOP grammar. Yes, the single-dispatch OOP languages descending from C and C++ generally use `noun.verb(arg)`, but there are plenty of languages that use `verb noun arg` or something entirely else. Likening methods to verbs is OK when explaining OOP, but taking that similarity too literally is misleading.

Comment: @amon: Nobody reduced OOP to a noun-verb relationship.  Certainly not me.  Obviously there is more to OOP than just noun-verb.  But the solution is `verb(noun)`, not `nouv(arf)erb`.  See [Steve Yegge's post](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html) about this.  And since that's all you chose to focus on, you clearly missed the larger point.

Comment: @amon: See the edits I've made to my answer, in response to your comments.

Answer (score 3):

There are quite a number of languages that have "keyword selectors". In those languages, arguments are passed after a colon inside the message selector. E.g., the following is valid syntax in (at least) Smalltalk, Self, Us, Korz, Fancy, Slate, Newspeak, Objective-C, Objective-C++, Objective-Modula-2, and possibly others:

```
anArray at: 3 put: "Hello".
```

This puts the string `"Hello"` at index `3` of `anArray`.

It is not *quite* what you want, though, since it only allows arguments after selector parts, not before.

I *know* I have seen a language that allows what you want somewhere, but I can't for the life of me remember the name.

---

The answers to the related question mentioned in the comments above list a couple of languages that support your exact syntax: Agda, Inform7, TeX, Gherkin, robotframework scripting language.